How to restrict access to a specific VPC in AWS
I have a case when I need to create a set of permissions for a group and the permissions are comprised of both managed and an inline policy. The group should have the ViewOnlyAccess and AmazonInspector2ReadOnlyAccess managed policies. And an inline policy
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "a4b:Get*",
        "account:Get*",
        "glue:GetConnections",
        "securityhub:BatchImportFindings",
        "ssm-incidents:List*",
        "wellarchitected:List*"
      ],
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}

But I want these permissions to provide access to a single vpc. How do I achieve that?
I tried writing a policy specifically for the targeted vpc but that did not work?
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "ec2:DescribeInstances"
      ],
      "Resource": "*",
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "ec2:Vpc": "vpc-xxxx"
        }
      }
    }
}

Also, since not everything is tied to the vpc, is it better to write a policy that targets the resource tags?

The only available key on ec2:DescribeInstances is ec2:Region which you can see here. You cannot restrict the DescribeInstances API request to a specific VPC ID through a policy. You have to do it with a vpc-id parameter on the actual API request.

The inline policy you have shown uses Actions that are mostly unrelated to VPCs.

I have also tried the policy below to give access to only the resources with the specific tag but that didn't seem to work as well.
{
"Effect": "Deny",
"Action": "",
"Resource": "",
"Condition": {
"StringNotEquals": {
"aws:ResourceTag/env": "tst"
}
}
}

{         "Sid": "DenyAllActionWithoutTag",         "Effect": "Deny",         "Action": "*",         "Resource": "*",         "Condition": {"StringNotEquals": {"aws:ResourceTag/env": "test"}}     }  - I just tested in IAM simulators this IAM policy and if your resources don't have tag test all action will be denied.

Did you want to attach ViewOnlyAccess and AmazonInspector2ReadOnlyAccess AWS-managed policies for specific instances?

@EugeneK, I wanna use those managed policies as is and then write a separate policy that will make sure those managed policies would work for all the resources with the resource tag env:test

This is not possible. The ec2:DescribeInstances API call only supports ec2:Region condition keys.
Source: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_amazonec2.html#amazonec2-actions-as-permissions. Search for DescribeInstances under Actions.

Thanks, that makes sense.
I have also tried the policy below to give access to only the resources with the specific tag but that didn't seem to work as well.
{
"Effect": "Deny",
"Action": "",
"Resource": "",
"Condition": {
"StringNotEquals": {
"aws:ResourceTag/env": "tst"
}
}
}
